# CSS and Materialize

Tags: css

I have a question about my CCS code.
I got a button with above that a loading bar (that shows when you click on the button).

If I press the button, the loading bar comes but it pushes the button down and I've tried to make the button to position `fixed'.

Can someone tell me if there is another way or can you give a solution to my own code.

My HTML code with the button and loading bar:

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m8 l6">
            <div id="loader" class="center"></div>
            <a id="submitForm" class="btn green waves-effect waves-light">Add Contact
                <i class="material-icons right">add</i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS for the button, the .btn selector is a class from materialize:

```
 .btn{
   background-color: #88969c !important;
   position: fixed !important;
   margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m8 l6">
                <div id="loader" class="center"></div>
                <a id="submitForm" class="btn green waves-effect waves-light">Add Contact
                    <i class="material-icons right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        (function () {

            $('#submitForm').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if($("#submitForm").hasClass('disabled')){
                    return;
                }

                $('#submitForm').addClass('disabled');

                var randId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 19990307) + 1);
                $('#loader').append('<div id="'+ randId +'" class="progress"><div class="indeterminate"></div></div>');

                var name = $("#name").val();
                var phonenumber = $("#phonenumber").val();

                $("#name").val('');
                $("#phonenumber").val('');

                var data = {
                    name: name,
                    phonenumber: phonenumber
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'addNew',
                    data: data,
                    method: 'post',
                    success: function (data) {
                        Materialize.toast(' '+ data +' ', 4000, 'cool white-text');
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#'+ randId +'').fadeOut(150, function () {
                            $('#'+ randId +'').remove();
                            $('#submitForm').removeClass('disabled');
                        });
                    },

                })

            })

        })();
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make `.btn { position: static; }`. So that when ever loading bar comes your **btn** also shift itself down. And for making this happen (shifting and all). You have to use javascript or jquery.